# Two way fixed effect regression in R

Tags: r

My panel data frame has 25 variables and more than 2000 observations. I am trying to conduct two way fixed effect regression by using `plm` package. However, I want to control the variations over the years as well as across the districts. But the following error message is popping up after running the regression:

> Error in if (model) z$model <- mf : 
>     argument is not interpretable as logical
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
>    extra arguments ‘index’, ‘effect’ will be disregarded

```
lm(hyv_aus ~ danger_days_aus+benefit_days_aus+abovemax_aus+belowmin_aus, data=new_final_data, index=c("district", "year"), model = "within", effect="twoways")
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `lm` function is designed to understand `index=c("district", "year"), model = "within", effect="twoways"`. To me this looks like a very confused posting. Did you perhaps copy code from some website and accidentally leave off the first letter of that function name?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am a new learner of econometrics in R and this is how many other people have posted their questions with codes on two way fixed effect regression. Do you have any suggestion please on any better codes ? Thanks.

Comment: So you did copy someone else code from the web? I think this is off-topic here (d/t lack of [MCVE] when asking about error-producing code as well as being primarily a methods question). You may get a better fit for advice about methods for building econometric models posting on the SO Quantitative Finance forum where this might be on-topic.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will check it there.